# Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe

Tags: php, apache

I am running 4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_64 with

I am running the following version of Apapche

```
 httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.37 (centos)
Server built:   Nov 12 2021 04:57:27
```

I have the following portion of config

```
cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | grep -v "#"

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80

LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache


ServerAdmin root@localhost


<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>


DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>


    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>


    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz



    AddType application/x-hhtp-php .php  .html
    AddType text/html .shtml .html
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>


EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

I am trying to add php support for my index.html file.

When I start the service I am getting the following error.

```
Mar 11 12:34:10 CentOs_RADIUS httpd[59830]: [Mon Mar 11 12:34:10.793520 2024] [php7:crit] [pid 59830:tid 140288103422272] Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to rec>
Mar 11 12:34:10 CentOs_RADIUS httpd[59830]: AH00013: Pre-configuration failed
```

I went over many online articles and tryed somelution listed there but non of it helped.
Could you please give me advice ehat I can try here?